# Remove @{} from output and place in command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to remove the @{} from the output of the $list coming from the CSV file.

I am trying to run the Command "Complete-DomainJoin -Identity $line -DagNumber 023" for each line inside the CSV file

```
#Complete-DomainJoin (MultipleObjects)

$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\DEPTComputers023DEPTComputers023.csv
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    Complete-DomainJoin -Identity $line -DagNumber 023 
}
```

When I run this powershell script it errors out because its placing the line item from the CSV into the command as @{xxxx}, from reading around it seems the common way to fix the issue is by adding -ExpandProperty variable but I have not found where to place it or I am not understanding how to implement it correctly.

Comment: How does your CSV file look like? Does it have headers?

Comment: Just a list of of the computer names, was done in excel in one column and then exported as a csv. @Olaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is in the first column with no header row, then you can try this:

```
# Name the first column
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\DEPTComputers023DEPTComputers023.csv -Header 'ComputerName'
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    # use the ComputerName property
    Complete-DomainJoin -Identity $row.ComputerName -DagNumber 023 
}
```

If there aren't any commas in the file at all, then just replace `Import-Csv` with `Get-Content`

the `@{property=value}` syntax means that your object has sub-properties, instead of being a single string

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, I have now identified another issue, that I don't know if it can be solved. The Complete-DomainJoin command has to be run outside of the import. It is a commandlet that is provided by my work and by itself is another set of code. The way the code is now, powershell is seeing it as inside the CSV I believe, error posted below.

Comment: Complete-DomainJoin: C:\Temp\Complete-DomainJoin(Multiple Objects).ps1:6:5
Line |
   6 |      Complete-DomainJoin -Identity $row.ComputerName -DagNumber 023
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Complete-DomainJoin' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script
     | file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
     | verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: In what form is it provided by your work? If it is a PowerShell Module, it would need to be placed in one of the predefined locations and then imported using ```Import-Module``` command. You can read more about modules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @bwdiehl you just need to run the command correctly, but that depends on how it was set up. If it's a script file with a parameter block, then `c:\path\to\Complete-DomainJoin.ps1 -Identity $row.ComputerName -DagNumber 023`. Otherwise, just run the `Complete-DomainJoin` file or import the module right at the beginning of your script